# Error installing RVM to OSX Mountain Lion. "Error running 'make -j2'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running through my first setup of Ruby on Rails on my Macbook Pro with OS X Mountain Lion. Have never had to configure a machine for development before, usually do design. When running the RVM install, I get this (after the ruby-1.9.3-p385 - #compiling line).

```
Error running 'make -j2', please read /Users/reuber1/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p385/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Not sure what to do from here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Dev tools from Apple? See rvm installation instructions for OS X: https://rvm.io/os/osx/

Comment: I'll have to double-check this. I simply installed Xcode Command Line tools for Mountain Lion prior, which ran fine from what I could tell (I'm working off of the instructions from http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book).

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going on in that post on the rvm site. Pretty sure the problem is with Xcode.

https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

Install that. Problem solved..

Comment: I'm on Mountain Lion. Those installs are for Snow Leopard & Lion.

Comment: Check out the readme. The 10.7 package will work with Mtn Lion. I'm using it with 10.8, myself..

Comment: Apologies…I was about to say, it's running through the installation for me now after running gcc installer. Fingers crossed, been trying to get this installed for almost a week now.

Comment: Think I got this working. Thanks a lot for your help. Running gcc-installer made life considerably easier.